# How to locate linux desktop menu shortcuts from command line?

Tags: linux, command-line, gnome, xfce4

I would like to run one of the shortcuts from command line (when I connect remotely, I don't need the entire desktop, I just want to use a specific app). I can access this shortcut when I run gnome or xfce. However, I couldn't find it (or any other shortcuts) from command line.

Any idea on how can I locate it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to https://developer.gnome.org/integration-guide/stable/desktop-files.html.en, they should be in `/usr/share/applications` (for globally installed apps) or `~/.local/share/applications` (for privately installed apps).